# every basis is monotone w.r.t. an equivalent norm $\||{x} \|| = \sup_n \|S_n x\|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, schauder-basis

I want to prove that every basis $\{x_n\}$ is monotone with respect to the equivalent
norm $\||x\|| = \sup_n \|S_n x\|$ where $S_n$ is the natural projections associated to the basis.
All that i can move
$$\||{S_N x}\|| = \displaystyle \sup_M \|S_M S_N x\| = \displaystyle \sup_{1 \leq M \leq N} \|S_M x\| \leq  \||{x}\||.$$ So, $\displaystyle \sup_N \||{S_N} \|| \leq 1.$
How i can prove that $\|| S_N \|| \geq 1$ to prove that $\sup_n \||{S_N} \|| = 1.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$||| S_Nx_1||| =|||x_1|||=\sup_n \|S_nx_1\|\geq \|S_1x_1\|=\|x_1\|=|||x_1|||$ and $x_1 \neq 0$. By definition of operator norm this implies $|||S_N||| \geq 1$.

Comment: what do you mean by $x_1$
can you clarify your answer more

Comment: $x_1$ is the first term in the sequence $(x_n)$. I am just using the fact that $\|Tx\| \geq \|x\|$ with $x \neq 0$ implies $\|T\|\geq 1$. This is because $\|Ty\| \geq 1$ where $y=\frac x {\|x\|}$ and $\|T\|$ is defined as the sup of $\|Ty\|$ over all unit vectors $y$. @Roba

Comment: thank you for your help but i don't know why $\||S_N x_1\||  = \||x_1\||$ and why $\||x\|| = \||x_1\||$

Comment: @Roba By the definition of the projections $S_n$ it follows that $S_n x_1=x_1$ for all $n$.